# Overflow `Label`

Tags: wpf, label

Is there any way to make a `Label` overflow? I am overlaying a `Label` over a `Combobox` to simulate default text, but the `Label` prevents the `Combobox` from getting focus when clicked. I would like to therefore set the `Label` width as 1 and overflow it.

By the way, I have seen the "watermark" workaround to the `Combobox` default text issue, but it is not viable in my use case so there is no need to suggest it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<Label IsHitTestVisible="false" Focusable="false" />` then the label won't intercept mouse clicks or receive the focus.

Answer (score 1):

to do what you want to do, you should just do:

```
MyLabel.IsHitTestVisible = false;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

this way you do not have to worry about overlapping.